# How to debug why Unity freezes?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am doing a collaboration with my school mates for a school project, but recently when I run Unity it freezes and I can't get it to unfreeze. I have uninstalled and reimported all the assets and my group mates also said that their Unity does not have this problem. I can't find a solution.

The project is being done in 2d. I was testing some logic while this happened to me. I was making a health bar test where it automatically goes down and there's a text box while follows it containing the actual number. Then suddenly the next day Unity decided to quit on me and not run at all.

### Update

Code:

```
public static float fillamount = 1f;
public float period = 1f;
public Image image;
private float time;
public float DoesItDecreaseOverTime = -0.1f;

private float tempnum;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    time += Time.deltaTime;

    while (fillamount <100 || fillamount > 0)
    {
        if (time >= period)
        {
            fillamount += DoesItDecreaseOverTime;
            time = 0;
        }
    }

    tempnum = (fillamount * 100);

    image.fillAmount = fillamount;

}
}
```

Comment: This question is far too broad and not well suited for these forums; this could be caused by many different things.

Comment: Posting parts of your code that are suceptible to cause the crash could help. But @JillevdW is right, this is quite broad. What debugging have you done up to this point?

Comment: ok. i want to test to see whether unity will actually compile so im giving it a bit of time. will upload some scripts after that

Comment: Does your unity freeze if you start a different or empty project? If so, maybe try reinstalling.

Comment: Sounds like an endless While loop or something similar. Can't be for sure untill we see some code!

Comment: How would we find out without any relevant code?

Comment: How have tried to debug this? Are you able to find an infinite loop by debugging your code? Let us know what you have tried so far.

Comment: Never ever use a while loop in unity. That is the number 1# cause of freezes in unity. Figure out a different way to do the same logic.

Answer (score 3):

After long days of frustration myself, I have found how to debug while unity freezes. I was doing stuff with trees (not the vegetation, the data structure) and for me it was very hard to determine where and what causes stack overflow. The stack overflow freezes unity so I can't see any debug that would have helped me to solve the problem. But now, I found the solution.

**SOLUTION**
So, I tried using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` which you should see in the output window of Visual Studio. But that doesn't seem to work with a unity project. Anyways, I started to think a little bit and came up with this class:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class Logger
{

    public Logger(string logFilePath)
    {
        if(!logFilePath.EndsWith(".log"))
            logFilePath += ".log";
        LogFilePath = logFilePath;
        if(!File.Exists(LogFilePath))
            File.Create(LogFilePath).Close();
        WriteLine("New Session Started");
    }

    public string LogFilePath { get; private set; }

    public void WriteLine(object message)
    {
        using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(LogFilePath, true))
            writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + message.ToString());
    }

}
```

Usage is like this:

```
Logger logger = new Logger(@"C:\Users\Soogbad\Desktop\MyLog.log");
logger.WriteLine("Hello World");
```

This creates a log file in which you can see all the logs you made. It works perfect! Even while unity is freezing.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid Loops in the update function (unless you fully control the loop), this function is called everyframe so if you perform long tasks in here you might experience framedrop and freezes.

In your case replace the while by a If and revert the conditions.

If you have unity pro you have the Profiler that will tell you what script/function is taking the most cpu time.

Comment: The free version of Unity now has a profiler. Also, loops are perfectly fine depending on the use case.

Comment: well you can loop if you have full control of what is in the loop. In his case it seems somehow he stays a lot in the loop as the conditions seems not to be met very often